# Incomplete Word Rectangle

Tags: word, english, grid-deduction

This is an incomplete [word rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square#Word_rectangles):

[image]

When completed, every row will contain a common English word with four letters, and every column will contain a word with five letters. All of these are common words that can be found in [this list of the top 10,000 words in the English language](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt). None of the words are names or abbreviations.

Can you fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got

> VAST, IDEA, TOLL, ABLE, LESS
>  VITAL, ADOBE, SELLS, TALES.
>  Wasn't sure about ADOBE, so I checked the word list linked by OP, it's there!

Comment: Did we just post an answer at the same time

Comment: I technically answered first lol, but I was editting my photo

Comment: Though my solution has an "R" instead of a  "T"

Comment: +1; I got exactly the same words when I tried independently. Uncovered your answer just to check for "duplication" and there goes... It was fun anyway so no regrets!

Answer (score 11):

There's multiple solutions, I'm sure, but here's one:

> [image]

***This is what happens when you play too much Scrabble***

Comment: Out of interest, how did you go about filling it in? Was 'v---l' or 'v--t' the easiest clues because of the rareness of the letter v, or what?

Comment: This, along with deep thought's answer, is the only 2 solutions.

Comment: @ZanyG Yup. I actually started with v--t and then went down: the -d-b- wasa the next most obvious one. And then v---l which filled itself in with the rest.

Comment: This is one of those cases where I really wish I could accept two answers. I'm giving it to deep thought because deep thought's answer was posted slightly before yours, and because deep thought's answer was the solution I had in mind, but your solution is equally good.