# Word Rectangle #2

Tags: word, english, grid-deduction

As with [my previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/79095/incomplete-word-rectangle), this is an unfinished [word rectangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square#Word_rectangles):

[image: word rectangle]

Can you fill in the blanks?

When completed, every row will contain a common English word with five letters, and every column will contain a word with four letters. All of the words appear [on this list of common English words](https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/blob/master/google-10000-english-no-swears.txt). None of the words are names (or other proper nouns) or abbreviations. I have verified that this puzzle has exactly one solution. (I should have checked that last time. Whoops.)

Comment: Might want to remove the mouse cursor from the picture.

Comment: @ZanyG - Hahaha. I can't *believe* I missed that. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @plasticinsect +1 for such nice rectangles! can you teach me your approach to make these puzzles? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton - Thanks. I must sheepishly confess I wrote a Perl program to search for them. The program is still very much a work in progress. (and may always be) However, I am quickly learning that the tricky part is actually choosing which letters to expose. People keep solving them within an hour. I have *got* to stop underestimating how good everyone here is at solving puzzles! :)

Comment: @plasticinsect For this one, the -W--R seemed suspicious and, as it turned out, there was only one word on the list that fit it. Once you have a word in place, you can sort of work out where vowels and consonants go, and from there it's just a little bit of trial and error. The hardest part of this puzzle was the left-most column: I kept on thinking we needed another vowel there. Might help you with making them.

Comment: @ZanyG - Oh good. That is the sort of process I was hoping for. The -W--R was indeed intended as the "opener". But maybe I can get away with fewer clues next time. (If you had said "I wrote a program to solve it." then I would have given up. :) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it.

> ```
> OWNER
> DROVE
> DATES
> SPENT
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Partial

Row 2:

> volvo (#7800 on list)

Column 5:

> root (#1941 on list)

Comment: Remember, no names or abbreviations. I'm counting any proper noun as a name here. (I just edited the post to clarify this.)